# Printing to file from console

Tags: c, linux, console, printf

I am writing a program on Linux in C where I cannot use `fprintf` to print to a file.  I can use `printf` to print in the console though.  How can I take the console output and write it to a file.

I tried `printf("echo whatever >> file.txt");` but as I suspected it doesn't run.

Thanks

Comment: `system("echo whatever >> file.txt");` should work but if you can't use `fprintf`, why could you use `system` ^^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running the program, append `> file.txt` to it should work.

`./program > file.txt`

IIRC, re-routes the STDOUT to the file.

Comment: This seems like the solution I was looking for.  It creates the file, but doesn't seem to write to it.  The program I'm running has an argument so shall I use it before or after the arg?  I did try both but to no avail...

Comment: What is the print that you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get your program to output some text and for the shell evaluate the output as a command.

This is unusual, one would normally separate the responsibilities of generating the text to the program, then let the shell redirect that output to a file:

foo.c contains:

```
...
printf("whatever");
...
```

Then run your program and redirect standard output to wherever you like:

```
$a.out >> file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Compile and run your program like that

```
./program > lala.txt
```

This will "push" all your `printf()`'s to `lala.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can [`freopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html) the `stdout` stream.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  if (freopen("5688371.txt", "a", stdout) == NULL) {
    /* error */
  }
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `freopen` or `dup2` as follows:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int f = open("test.txt", O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0666);
    dup2(f, 1);
    printf("Hello world\n");
    printf("test\n");
    close(f);
    return 0;
}
```